# In dvipng output, why does one side of equation expand to size of fractional side?

Tags: png

I have been using dvipng to produce png images of latex equations to be embedded in html, and the output is very nice. However, for equations with a fraction, the non-fraction side produces a font which is too big, almost as though it has expanded to respect the height of the fraction. My latex is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

$\nabla \times \mathbf{E} = \frac{\rho}{\varepsilon_0}$

\end{document}
```

and my command line arguments are

```
latex file.tex
dvipng -D 200 file.dvi -T tight -bg transparent
```

So for example, in this Maxwell equation, the 'del cross E' is noticably too large, whereas in a normal latex document this problem does not exist.

[image]

Is there anything wrong with my input?

Comment: Load `amsmath` and write `\dfrac` instead of `\frac`; does it do what you're looking for?

Comment: @egreg Yes, in fact that appears to work! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably comparing this result with what you get when writing

```
\[
\nabla \times \mathbf{E} = \frac{\rho}{\varepsilon_0}
\]
```

When TeX typesets a formula to be displayed, as in the example above, it uses `\displaystyle` where fractions are bigger. The input

```
$\nabla \times \mathbf{E} = \frac{\rho}{\varepsilon_0}$
```

produces a formula typeset in `\textstyle`, where fractions are reduced in size because the formula is supposed to be printed inline and large objects would spoil the pagination balance. Moreover, in `\textstyle` exponents are a bit lower than in `\displaystyle`.

You have two choices:

```
$\displaystyle\nabla \times \mathbf{E} = \frac{\rho}{\varepsilon_0}$
```

or

```
$\nabla \times \mathbf{E} = \dfrac{\rho}{\varepsilon_0}$
```

(requires `\usepackage{amsmath}`): the `\dfrac` command typesets the fraction as if it were given in `\displaystyle`.

In this particular case there will be no difference among the two; there would be a slight difference if exponents are involved and a *big* difference for "big operators" such as `\sum`. Take your pick.

Comment: Nice explanation, much appreciated. I now understand why the problem existed, as well as how to remedy the problem.

Comment: Please, have a look at the site FAQ, particularly to http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask